# Using plotly i want to plot a chart with filters

Tags: pandas, plotly

Using plotly I want to plot a chart like this with filter(menu). The first chart is just one State. I tried adding the menu but the chart is not clear. And when I try to change the selection im getting a totally different chart and sometimes a blank one. This is a sample of my dataframe[image: Using plotly I want to plot a chart like this with filter(menu)]

[image: I tried adding the menu but the chart is not clear]
[image: This is a sample of my dataframe]

below is my code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

for name in combined_df['name'].unique():
    filtered_df = combined_df[combined_df['name'] == name]
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x=filtered_df['quarter_year'],
            y=filtered_df['count'],
            name=name
        )
    )

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        go.layout.Updatemenu(
            active=0,
            buttons=[
                dict(
                    label=state,
                    method='update',
                    args=[
                        {'visible': [name == s for s in combined_df['name'].unique()]},
                        {'title': name, 'showlegend': True}
                    ]
                ) for state in combined_df['state'].unique()
            ]
        )
    ]
)

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: The response has been updated as data has been provided for use in the graph.
For this graph, the filtering by drop button is a button argument that controls whether to show or hide the data. As an initial graph, we only show andaman-&nicobar-islands and hide all other countries. Next, we need a list of show/hide buttons for all states, so once we have a list of False for all state counts, we update the list by sliding True (show by name) on the 5-line graph.

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.read_csv('./data/Aggregate - Transaction Amount and Count.csv', index_col=0)

fig = go.Figure()

for s in df['state'].unique():
    dff = df.query('state == @s')
    for n in dff['name'].unique():
        dfn = dff.query('name == @n')
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
                mode='lines',
                x=dfn['quarter_year'],
                y=dfn['count'],
                name=n,
                visible=False,
            ))
        
for k in [0,1,2,3,4]:
    fig.update_traces(visible=True, selector=k)

buttons = []
for i,s in enumerate(df['state'].unique()):
    button=dict(
        label=s,
        method='update',
        args=[{'visible': [False] * len(fig.data)}, {'title': s, 'showlegend': True}]
        )
    button['args'][0]['visible'][i*5] = True
    button['args'][0]['visible'][i*5+1] = True
    button['args'][0]['visible'][i*5+2] = True
    button['args'][0]['visible'][i*5+3] = True
    button['args'][0]['visible'][i*5+4] = True

    buttons.append(button)
    
fig.layout.updatemenus = [{'buttons': buttons}]

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The response has been updated with the data provided. If it does not work, please comment to me.